# How does Reinhardt's extension of the set-theoretic universe beyond $V_\Omega$ work?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals, transfinite-recursion, alternative-set-theories, transfinite-induction

In this [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/100981/ultrainfinitism-or-a-step-beyond-the-transfinite/101009#101009) it is stated that in William Reinhardt's paper 'Remarks on reflection principles, large cardinals, and elementary embeddings' (1974)

> Reinhardt suggests extending the set-theoretic universe beyond $V_\Omega$ (where $\Omega$ denotes the class of ordinals) to some "virtual realm" of larger objects: $V_{\Omega+1}$, $V_{\Omega+\Omega}$, and so on.

I have not been able to find a free copy of the paper & was wondering if someone could elaborate on the method Reinhardt suggests.

Additionally:

- Does this method have a name?
- What is the upper limit of this method?

Any additional online references for further reading would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Reinhardt's paper is not easy to locate. A reasonable account with some details is available in P. Maddy's "Believing the axioms. II".

Comment: That said, the paper appears to be currently available [here](https://canvas.eee.uci.edu/files/2966398/download?download_frd=1).

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo: I've seen papers from 1891 that were more readable than this scan.

Comment: @Asaf Yeah, but only because they didn't have large cardinals back then. :-)